# Void folder is taking megabytes of space in OSX

Tags: macos, fish, macos-mojave

```
xxx@MacBook- ~/D/p/a/Project5_min> du -sh *
2.6M    app
4.0K    build.gradle
 60K    gradle
4.0K    gradle.properties
8.0K    gradlew
4.0K    gradlew.bat
4.0K    instruction.txt
4.0K    local.properties
4.0K    Project5.iml
4.0K    settings.gradle
xxx@MacBook-Pro ~/D/p/a/Project5_min> du -sh
 36M    .
```

I am trying to determine what is taking so much space in Project5 folder. I used `du -sh *` to get a list of all files and folders and their size. Then I used `du -sh` to determine the main folder size itself.

Space taken by the files listed after the firs command is around 2.7M, space taken by the main folder is 36M

36 - 2.7 = 33.3. What is happening with 33MB of space in this folder? How can I determine which file or folder is taking the missing memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have hidden files or directories ie begining with .

If you do then `du -sh *` does not find them as * expands to the non hidden entries only.

Try `du -h` to show all the directories.

Comment: You are right, I did not realize that -sh * option is not showing hidden files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If there are a lot of subfolders, you can use `du -hd1` to list only the top-level directories.